# Java server, Java Client remote calls can we remove the need for serialization

Tags: java, serialization, rmi

I have a JAVA web application which has some methods defined in its service classes.
I have to write a test client to test these service methods. Test client will run outside the web app.

I know RMI can be used when both server and client are in java.
But in our case the classes returned by service methods are not serializable.
I don't want to devote time making these classes serializable.

Is there a toll like RMI which doesn't require classes to be serializable?

Comment: I am trying to use java writeobject and readobject methods (using json to write and read) and then use this with RMI.

Answer (score 0):

When I don't want to deal with the hassle of serialization, I often use [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). This library will parse any object into XML and vice versa pretty smoothly. Then, it will be easy to send XML to your client/server.

Comment: Does RMI forbid sending `String` ?

Comment: Of course not. If sending all parameters as `String` is part of your answer it should appear in your answer.

Comment: Take the object => use xstream to get a `String` of XML => send the `String` using RMI => use xstream to rebuild the object => Tada :)

Comment: Implementing all that would waste considerably more time than making the objects concerned  Serializable.

Comment: My personal experience disagree with you. Putting it aside, one would need to actually see the code to make a decision: you are probably right if there is not a lot of dependency between the class. But, eh, it has been over two years, OP probably find a solution that suited his needs

Answer (score 0):

No. Java RMI requires serialization.